# cannot find method getExportedKeys( ) in Magento

Tags: magento

I am using PHPStorm which is really a great search tool, and I'm searching from the root Magento folder (not just the `app` folder).  I'm searching for:

```
function getExportedKeys
```

and even

```
function\s+getExportedKeys
```

using regexp.  Where would this be, is this a native method or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any context, my best guess is that this is just using the [inherited `Varien_Object` getter (i.e. `__call()`)](http://alanstorm.com/magento_varien_object_debugging). Look for `setExportedKeys()` and you will probably find the source of the data.

> This is a common pattern in Object Oriented Programming. By having all your objects of a particular type share a common ancestor, you can write methods that are shared across your entire code base.
>
> One of the things `Varien_Object` provides is Magento’s famous “getter” and “setter” methods. These methods are implemented via [PHP’s magic `__call` method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call). Since the customer object referenced above doesn’t have a `setFirstName` function, PHP calls `Varien_Object`’s `__call` method...

Comment: that gets 8 occurrences and only gets the CALLS to that method.  Searching "Magento getExportedKeys" or even just getexportedkeys on Google doesn't return anything related to PHP that I can find.  Hmmm...

Comment: @OliverWilliams - Yes, that confirms my suspicion. Those are basic `Varien_Object` getters and setters. Check out the article I linked.

Comment: so to find out what you have on `exported_keys`, either try to find `setExportedKeys` or fiend the right `exported_keys` field in your db.